# Prototype - var x = [] - adds functions onto x

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I'm new with Prototype, but I use jQuery always. I have a site where I need to use jQuery as well as Prototype. I am having problems with the following code:

```
var x = [];
console.log(x);
for (var l in x)
{
console.log(l);
}
```

Running this code, x contains the following:

```
    each
    eachSlice
    all
    any
    collect
    detect
    findAll
    select
    grep
    include
    member
    inGroupsOf
    inject
    invoke
    max
    min
    partition
    pluck
    reject
    sortBy
    toArray
    entries
    zip
    size
    inspect
    find
    _reverse
    _each
    clear
    first
    last
    compact
    flatten
    without
    uniq
    intersect
    clone
```

Expected Result (without Prototype):

```
There are no child objects
```

Any reason why Prototype does this, and how to stop it?!

Thanks

Comment: [Never, ever use for-in-loops on arrays!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)

Comment: I know this isn't your question, but if you're using Prototype, don't forget about the many incredibly useful Enumerable methods, the most straightforward being [Enumerable.each()](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Enumerable/prototype/each/).

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't use [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) for arrays, and this is exactly why.

`for...in` loops through all the properties of an object.  This includes its properties (in this case, array indexes), and properties added to the `prototype`.

For arrays, just use a normal [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop.

```
var x = [];
console.log(x);
for(var i = 0, len = x.length; i<len; i++){
    console.log(i, x[i]);
}
```

Note: I do `var i = 0, len = x.length` because it only grabs the `length` from the array once, instead of on every iteration.  It *may* be faster.

Comment: It's just because I'm using a library called ui.selectmenu and the code is written like this, but I will modify the code :)

Comment: @GeorgeWoodward: Or yell at the library creators to fix it :-P

Comment: He is asking how to get the properties of the object and not the properties of the entire inheritance chain.. so you would need a `x.hasOwnProperty(l)`

Comment: All posts here are saying not to use `for...in` for arrays. Could you explain what `for...in` is actually doing in this case? I.e. how does it reach the output it does?

Comment: @corsiKa it's showing all of the enumerable properties of `[]`, which on old, lame, browsers (and with Prototype.js) happens to include the enumerable properties of `Array.prototype`.

Comment: @Waltzy: `hasOwnProperty` is only needed when doing `for...in`, not when doing a normal `for`.

Comment: @Alnitak Ah I see. So it's displaying the properties as opposed to the elements. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @corsiKa yes, that's right.  To further complicate things, the elements of an array are _also_ properties!

Comment: I was mainly wanting to find out why it happens and now I know :)

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't use `for..in` on an array, you should use `for( i=0; i<length; i++)`. But that aside:

```
for( l in x) {
    if( x.hasOwnProperty(l)) {
        // l is a property of your object
    }
}
```

This basically ignores the prototype chain for looping.

Comment: IMHO, in code targeting ES5 there's no need for `.hasOwnProperty()` - new stuff added to the Array prototype should be flagged by the programmer as non-enumerable.

Comment: @Alnitak: Not by default.  Only if you flag it as such yourself.

Comment: @Rocket yes, that's what I meant ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `for ... in` you're enumerating all of the (enumerable) *properties* of the array, and not just the numeric indexes.

Since Prototype.js adds lots of new functions to `Array.prototype` and fails to mark them as non-enumerable, those all appear in the list of properties too.